# creating legend for scatter3 plot (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, legend, scatter-plot

I have a matrix points `X` in 3 dimensions (`X` is a `Nx3` matrix) and those points belong to clusters. The cluster it belongs is given by the `Nx1` vector `Cluster` (it has values like 1,2,3,...). So, I am plotting it on `scatter3` like this:

```
scatter3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3),15,Cluster)
```

It works fine, but I would like to add a legend to it, showing the colored markers and the cluster it represents.

For example, if i have 3 clusters, I would like to have a legend like:

```
<blue o> - Cluster 1
<red o> - Cluster 2
<yellow o> - Cluster 3
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Are you referring to `RGB` planes in particular? or you just want to label the clusters?

Comment: @bonCodigo I just want to label them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `scatter3`, I suggest you use `plot3`, which will make labeling much simpler:

```
%# find out how many clusters you have
uClusters = unique(Cluster);
nClusters = length(uClusters);

%# create colormap
%# distinguishable_colormap from the File Exchange 
%# is great for distinguishing groups instead of hsv
cmap = hsv(nClusters);

%# plot, set DisplayName so that the legend shows the right label
figure,hold on
for iCluster = 1:nClusters
    clustIdx = Cluster==uClusters(iCluster);
    plot3(X(clustIdx,1),X(clustIdx,2),X(clustIdx,3),'o','MarkerSize',15,...
       'DisplayName',sprintf('Cluster %i',uClusters(iCluster)));
end

legend('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you use

- `legend`

Code:

```
h = scatter3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3),15,Cluster)
hstruct = get(h);
legend(hstruct.Children, "Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Cluter3");
```

or

- [annotation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html).

Comment: yes, sure, but what should I use as argument of legend? The first argument I put inside legend wotks fine (`legend('cluster1')`) .It shows the first marker with the correct legend, but only for the first one. It won't work for all of them.

Comment: @DanielX2010 please try the following update and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I had also tried that, but the result is bizarre. He gives a warning saying `Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries.` and the result is a strange legend (uploaded result here: http://s1.postimage.org/l9k7xm9xb/untitled.png)

Comment: @Daniel the picture is too small too view properly. Did you try Jonas method? The other way would be explicityly name each cluster...