# Legend on scatter3 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I was expecting that to work, but I am missing what is a "vector of handles", from MATLAB helpfile.

> LEGEND(M), where M is a string matrix or cell array of strings, and
>
> LEGEND(H,M) where H is a vector of handles to lines and patches also
>   works.

```
myone = ones(20,1);
mytwo = ones(20,1)+1;
rows = vertcat(myone,mytwo);
mylabels = {'Alpha', 'Beta'};

figure
grouplabels = mylabels(rows);
h = scatter3(rand(40,1),rand(40,1),rand(40,1),20,rows,'filled'), ...
    view(-33,22)
legend(handle(h),grouplabels)

xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```

[image]

Comment: `h` is itself a `handle`, but not a vector, rather a handle to a single scalar scatter series object. Anyway, see for instance [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006678/creating-legend-for-scatter3-plot-matlab).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known bug in MATLAB's scatter plots, and requires downloading a patch (or waiting until a newer version). http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1283854

Comment: Mathworks suggests that `gscatter()` is also an option, and appears to work correctly with `legend()`

Comment: @gariepy, this bug is irrelevant. It only affects 2015b and no other version. And in this particular case the problem is clearly different and reproducible on all other Matlab versions.

Comment: @gariepy can you make a 3D plot with gscatter?  I tried that but I messed up with the projection 3D space on 2D.

Comment: @gariepy OK thanks I found that in mathworks for [3D-using-gscatter](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92577-how-can-i-create-a-3d-grouped-scatter-plot-in-statistics-toolbox-7-2-r2009b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `h`, the output of `scatter3`, is a single handle. It's not an array of handles with the same size as your data (which is what you imply when trying to set 40x1 array of labels on it, ignoring irrelevant `handle` wrapper). And it's not even an array of two handles as one may have thought (one per color). So you cannot set legend like this. One way around would be to plot all the points of one color at a time:

```
hFig = figure();
axh = axes('Parent', hFig);
hold(axh, 'all');
h1 = scatter3(rand(20,1),rand(20,1),rand(20,1),20,'b','filled');
h2 = scatter3(rand(20,1),rand(20,1),rand(20,1),20,'r','filled');
view(axh, -33, 22);
grid(axh, 'on');
legend(axh, [h1,h2], {'Alpha', 'Beta'});
```

[image]